# Information Truncated When Printed

Tags: css, winforms, pdf, browser, printing

when i'm printing my notes in windows application using internet explored browser some of my content in the right side of the notes is truncated. I verified my style sheets which is having margin_right with negative value. Is this one causing the problem when printing to PDF or some other things i need to find for the fix??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use @media print to style the document for printing purpose.

Comment: already added <style media="print">
.noprint {display: none;}
</style>

Comment: but i don't think so, this property is affecting my contents